# Why does the execution speed of the while loop change over time?

Tags: mysql, c, performance, while-loop, query-optimization

We have a Time issue in a C while loop. in one part of the program, the while loop receives information from a sensor via the SPI protocol and stores it in a Mysql database, The problem appears when we are checking the stored data.
For example, 600 data per second is stored in the database, but in some seconds the number of stored data is reduced to 400, and after a few seconds it returns to 600 per second, and so on.
I know that the data transfer rate from the sensor works on a fixed clock and cannot be changed.
But I do not know where this problem arises.

here is while loop code in c:

```c
 while(1)
        {

            tx_buff[0] = 0x08 ;
            tx_buff[0] = (tx_buff[0] << 1) | 1;
            tx_buff[1] = 0xFF;
            tx_buff[2] = 0xFF;
            tx_buff[3] = 0xFF;
            tx_buff[4] = 0xFF;
            tx_buff[5] = 0xFF;
            tx_buff[6] = 0xFF;
            tx_buff[7] = 0xFF;
            tx_buff[8] = 0xFF;
            tx_buff[9] = 0xFF;
            tinkerboard_set_gpio_state(24, LOW);
            tinkerboard_spi_transfer(SPI2, tx_buff, rx_buff,10, mode);
            tinkerboard_set_gpio_state(24, HIGH);
            X_unsigned = (rx_buff[1]<<16) | (rx_buff[2]<<8)| (rx_buff[3]);
            X_unsigned = X_unsigned >> 4;
            X_signed = adc24to32(X_unsigned);
            Y_unsigned = (rx_buff[4]<<16) | (rx_buff[5]<<8)| (rx_buff[6]);
            Y_unsigned = Y_unsigned >> 4;
            Y_signed = adc24to32(Y_unsigned);
            Z_unsigned = (rx_buff[7]<<16) | (rx_buff[8]<<8)| (rx_buff[9]);
            Z_unsigned = Z_unsigned >> 4;
            Z_signed = adc24to32(Z_unsigned);

printf(" X=%5.4f Y=%5.4f Z=%5.4f \n",
X_signed*0.0039,Y_signed*0.0039,Z_signed*0.0039);
sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO PO(x,y,z) VALUES(%5.4f,%5.4f,%5.4f)",
X_signed*0.0039,Y_signed*0.0039,Z_signed*0.0039);

//conect to sql
     mysql_query(conn, query);
    
        }
```

Comment: `and stores it in a mysql database` - is that a disk IO (file system) operation?

Comment: If yes, then, it is not something to rely on for RT responses, as the FS at any time may "choose" to reorganize, thus yield a considerable lag. You should generally set up a different thread for doing this operation, and from your `while` loop, send it as a message to that other thread.

Comment: yes it is .@ goodvibration

Comment: Same goes for printing BTW - you should ideally have another thread just for that (aka *logging thread*).

Comment: I have to try this way . saved data in another thread ?

Comment: You set up several threads, which interact with each other via message queues. Here you need to send that data to the thread which stores it into the SQL file. In the cases where the FS operation takes longer, the message queue of that thread will become more populated (with messages not yet handled). Then, once that operation is completed, the queue will gradually "return to normal", with only a few messages pending in it. So you should make sure to use a large enough message queue, in order to handle occasional laggings.

Comment: Some Unix schedulers also penalize processes that were given execution time in the past few seconds in favor of those that have not. This may lead to a form of oscillating processor time.

Comment: Our OS is a distribution of Debian . if the problem is from there, how can we solve it? I mean, is there a way to solve this problem at all? @Jens

Comment: You could play around with the `nice` value for the process, increasing scheduling priority. See the man page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

First, open a connection to your MySql server and reuse it. Don't open a new connection for every insert: it's too slow. And keep in mind that MySql connection objects are *not* thread-safe.

Second, MySql handles bulk insert operations most efficiently if you bundle many of them into a single database transaction.   And your project does bulk insertions.

A suitable number of insert operations to bundle together is 100 or so. This helps the MySql server's efficiency because most of the insertion work happens upon transaction commit. If you don't wrap your inserts in `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` MySql does autocommit. That means every insertion is also a transaction, and the overhead gets out of hand.

This is fairly easy to organize. When your connection is first opened, set a countdown variable to 100, and issue `START TRANSACTION;` to MySql.

As you do each insert, decrement your countdown variable.  When it hits zero, reset it and do a `COMMIT;` and then another `START TRANSACTION;`.

This won't turn your project into a hard real-time project, but it will help a lot with MySql overhead.

And, consider running MySql on a different host machine.